# What does this expression 引き気味 mean in English ? [Manga]

Tags: grammar, expressions, manga, japanese-to-english

Context: MC's thought about a character's reaction (A-san), after she is observing MC and his team talking. She looks surprised because she has never thought that they will decided to help her and says "Ehh?"

> けど、そんな俺たちのやり取りを眺めてたA-sanが漏らしたのはさっきのB-sanを間違えた時以上に**引き気味**の「えええ」だった

(A-san just a while ago had acted impolitely with B-san, mistook B-san with someone else)

Can someone help me understand this expression **引き気味** correctly ? Thanks in advance ~!

Comment: Try image search for [ドン引き](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?p=%E3%83%89%E3%83%B3%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8D) and [引くわー](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?p=%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8F%E3%83%BC). 引き[気味](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%B0%97%E5%91%B3-1) is a little milder version of this.

Comment: you mean "taken a back because surprised /shock " ?

Comment: I'm not sure what "take a back" means... ドン引き is a strong reaction, but 引き気味 may describe a small reaction like losing enthusiasm. See the context carefully.

Comment: I can imagine she is shocked and took a step back ,like 1 character I saw in anime ( because like the context I provided ,she did not think that MC team would help her that easily/that fast